# Whats the best practice in managing the versions of react native apps?

Tags: android, react-native

Right now, we have react native apps for android and iOS and also plan to use Code Push if there are changes in the js files alone.

Lets say we release our first version of the android app which is 1.0.0. Then after few days, we have changes in the js code and do a codepush v1 (using Appcenter).

Do I need to release a new android version 1.0.1 (with the same js code)? Or Only release the v1.0.1 when there are only changes in the native side?
Whats the pros and cons of each?

Or is there an easy way to manage and track versioning of changes in the native and js codes?

Answer (score 1):

You can have versioning for binary code(native side) and JS side separate. I personally do that in my projects.

via Codepush, you can release only javascript code changes, so better to keep a track of these changes in JS side itself.
To do that, you can make a constants file and put version as,

```
const Constants = {
     APP_VERSION: '1.9.10.1',
}
```

Here if,

- I have a small change like a fix, then I'll update APP_VERSION to 1.9.10.2 and make codepush release.
- I have a minor feature added for example, "added flash support in camera", then I'll update APP_VERSION to 1.9.11 and make codepush release.
- I have made a new big feature like camera support itself then I'll update APP_VERSION to 1.10 and make codepush release.
- I have made full refactor to app, I mean a big change, then I'll update APP_VERSION to 2.0 and make codepush release.

For binary (native) side code change, for example in android's java side, you can keep track in file android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.2.2"  // here
    ....
}
```

Let me know if it works for you